# How to Trigger a Piece of Audio to Play from a Countdown Clock

Tags: events, audio, triggers, countdown

I have a website and I need a piece of audio to automatically start playing on the site at 11:57pm EST nightly.

What is the best way to do this? With a countdown clock? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: easy way would to use a html audio tag..give it some ID..and get it played by a script at 11:57 est

Comment: should I put a code with explanation ?

Comment: Please give us more information about the website and exactly what/why  you are wanting this audio to play. Cron job could be a possibility, JavaScript countdown, etc.  Do you want it to just play on any open browser windows?  If so, you'll need to keep the page alive for a very long duration.  More information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple audio which play at 11:57:00 pm everyday

I have made a sticky clock & binded the time ..and repeating an audio play event at a desired time every day

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);     
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
    if(document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML == "23:57:00"){
         PLayAudio();
    };
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

function PLayAudio(){
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
  x.play()
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
 <p>Audio will play at 11:57 pm !!!!</p>
<div id="txt"></div> 
<audio  id="myAudio" controls>   
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
```